# Django blog UserProfile model

Tags: django, model, blogs

I am creating a Django `blog` app and I already set up a `Post` and `Comment` models, both with a `ForeignKey` relationship to Django's builtin `User` model:

**models.py**

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    writer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="blogs")

class Comment(models.Model):
    writer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_comments')
```

If I add a `UserProfile` model to this blog app, would I need to change the foreign key relationship in my post model to this:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    writer = models.ForeignKey("UserProfile", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="blogs")
```

Thanks

**PS**
I want only admin users to have profiles and to be able to click on their profiles to view the posts they have created.

Regular users do not have the ability to create posts. They can only comment and like the posts.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Will it affect the model instances I created already if I change the foreign key relationship to UserProfile in place of User (In the Post model)?

Comment: Yes. You will be replacing the field. When making migrations, Django will ask you to provide a default value for the existing instances.

Comment: What kind of default value can I provide in this case?

Comment: An `interger` that corresponds to an `id` in the `UserProfile` model, or an instance of `UserProfile` model. That means you will have to have some `UserProfile` objects created first.